# Add spaces between string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am learning regular expression,hence asking this question. I have a string

String time=7AM-9PM;

I need to add spaces so that the string would come out like this

time=7 AM - 9 PM.

I have tried so far the following regular expression

time.replaceAll("(\d{1})", "$1 ");

and it is giving output

9 AM-7 PM

Now I just need the space before and after -. Can someone suggest what else I need to add in the regex to achieve the final output.

Thank You

Comment: time.replaceAll("(?!^)([A-Z])", " $1");

Comment: What where your issues with what you tried? In what way did it not work? (Btw, did you assign the return value back to `time`?)

Comment: You should edit your question to show what you have tried and what happened. Comments are useful for this sort of thing, but people new to this question shouldn't have to read the whole comments thread to find out basic information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried `7AM-10PM` you'd find that `10` would be split up like `1 0`: presumably not what you want!

I managed to do it with 2 replaceAlls:

```
String time = "7AM-10PM"
System.out.println(time
  .replaceAll("([0-9]+)", "$1 ")   //spaces around numbers
  .replaceAll("([\\-])", " $1 ")); //spaces around '-'
```

result : `7 AM - 10 PM`